# Is the checkpoint requires for the delta lake merge operation in a streaming job

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, upsert, delta-lake

I have an understanding that for a [spark streaming merge](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/delta-update.html#language-scala) it's helpful to have a checkpoint location specified to not process stuff twice on the job restart (even if the operation is idempotent and ins't mentioned in [example notebook](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/delta-update.html#slowly-changing-data-scd-type-2-operation-into-delta-tables)). Is it correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't specify the location of the checkpoint, each time all the data will be reprocessed.

Comment: just maybe to extend - it should be "all source data"